# Combine CSS psuedo classes on transition

Tags: css

I'm trying to transition a child element when the parent element is focused.

I want to do something like:

```
parent:focus{
//do something to first-child
}
```

Is this possible, or does this require JS?

Comment: If my answer bellow doesn't answer your question, you might want to share more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, or not.  If you do...

```
.parent:active .child {
    /* Style */
}
```

The style will be applied to `.child` elements inside the focused `.parent`.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X6KjC/) that shows how it works.  You can click anywhere in the big div to change the smaller (child) divs.

Comment: I updated my post.  After playing around with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X6KjC/), I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
parent:focus CHILD {
//do what you want on the child
}
```

Example:

```
ul li:focus a {
color:#000;
}
```

Even if I'm not sure it will work with `:focus` that is usually used on inputs. It would be better to use it with `:hover` (for example).